# Error when trying to update python / anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I use python 3.7.0 by Anaconda on Windows 10 x64, I don't have a virtual machine or other programming platforms installed.
I recently opened my Spyder and I can't run any of my programs, I always get an error message like:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_path' from 'matplotlib' (C: \ PYTHON \ Anaconda \ lib \ site-packages \ matplotlib \ __ init __. Py)"

I was running this version of python for almost 6 months.

At the Anaconda prompt I ran:

```
 conda update --all
```

And I got as a return:

```
Solving environment: -
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - defaults/win-64::astropy==3.0.2=py36h452e1ab_1
  - defaults/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py36h7e685f7_0
  - defaults/win-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36h8a29ca5_0
  - defaults/win-64::bokeh==0.12.16=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::bottleneck==1.2.1=py36hd119dfa_0
  - defaults/win-64::dask==0.17.5=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::datashape==0.5.4=py36h5770b85_0
  - defaults/win-64::h5py==2.7.1=py36h3bdd7fb_2
  - defaults/win-64::imageio==2.3.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py37_7
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_console==5.2.0=py37_1
  - defaults/win-64::matplotlib==2.2.2=py36h153e9ff_1
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_fft==1.0.1=py36h452e1ab_0
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_random==1.0.1=py36h9258bd6_0
  - defaults/win-64::numba==0.38.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - defaults/win-64::numexpr==2.6.5=py36hcd2f87e_0
  - defaults/win-64::numpy==1.14.3=py36h9fa60d3_1
  - defaults/win-64::numpy-base==1.14.3=py36h555522e_1
  - defaults/win-64::odo==0.5.1=py36h7560279_0
  - defaults/win-64::pandas==0.23.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - defaults/win-64::patsy==0.5.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytables==3.4.3=py36he6f6034_1
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-arraydiff==0.2=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-astropy==0.3.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-doctestplus==0.1.3=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pywavelets==0.5.2=py36hc649158_0
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-image==0.13.1=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-learn==0.19.1=py36h53aea1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::scipy==1.1.0=py36h672f292_0
  - defaults/win-64::seaborn==0.8.1=py36h9b69545_0
  - defaults/win-64::statsmodels==0.9.0=py36h452e1ab_0
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\PYTHON\Anaconda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _anaconda_depends-2019.03  |           py37_0           6 KB
    alabaster-0.7.12           |           py37_0          18 KB
    anaconda-custom            |           py37_1           3 KB
    asn1crypto-1.3.0           |           py37_0         164 KB
    babel-2.8.0                |             py_0         5.3 MB
    backports.os-0.1.1         |           py37_0          15 KB
    beautifulsoup4-4.8.2       |           py37_0         163 KB
    bitarray-1.2.1             |   py37he774522_0          82 KB
    bleach-3.1.0               |           py37_0         218 KB
    blosc-1.16.3               |       h7bd577a_0         137 KB
    bzip2-1.0.8                |       he774522_0         113 KB
    ca-certificates-2020.1.1   |                0         125 KB
    cffi-1.14.0                |   py37h7a1dbc1_0         223 KB
    click-7.0                  |           py37_0         121 KB
    cloudpickle-1.3.0          |             py_0          30 KB
    colorama-0.4.3             |             py_0          20 KB
    conda-4.8.2                |           py37_0         2.8 MB
    console_shortcut-0.1.1     |                3         107 KB
    curl-7.68.0                |       h2a8f88b_0         125 KB
    cython-0.29.15             |   py37ha925a31_0         1.8 MB
    dask-core-2.10.1           |             py_0         562 KB
    distributed-2.10.0         |             py_0         408 KB
    docutils-0.16              |           py37_0         667 KB

    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       229.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
  _anaconda_depends  pkgs/main/win-64::_anaconda_depends-2019.03-py37_0
  backports.os       pkgs/main/win-64::backports.os-0.1.1-py37_0
  fsspec             pkgs/main/noarch::fsspec-0.6.2-py_0
  hypothesis         pkgs/main/noarch::hypothesis-5.5.4-py_0
  joblib             pkgs/main/noarch::joblib-0.14.1-py_0
  matplotlib-base    pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-base-3.1.3-py37h64f37c6_0
  mock               pkgs/main/noarch::mock-4.0.1-py_0
  path               pkgs/main/win-64::path-13.1.0-py37_0
  powershell_shortc~ pkgs/main/win-64::powershell_shortcut-0.0.1-2
  pyreadline         pkgs/main/win-64::pyreadline-2.1-py37_1
  pytest-astropy-he~ pkgs/main/noarch::pytest-astropy-header-0.1.2-py_0
  tbb                pkgs/main/win-64::tbb-2020.0-h74a9793_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:
  asn1crypto                                   1.2.0-py37_0 --> 1.3.0-py37_0
  babel                                          2.7.0-py_0 --> 2.8.0-py_0
  beautifulsoup4                               4.8.1-py37_0 --> 4.8.2-py37_0
  cffi                                1.13.2-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 1.14.0-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  cloudpickle                                    1.2.2-py_0 --> 1.3.0-py_0
  importlib_metadata                           1.1.0-py37_0 --> 1.5.0-py37_0
  jinja2                                        2.10.3-py_0 --> 2.11.1-py_0
  json5                                          0.8.5-py_0 --> 0.9.1-py_0
  jupyterlab                             1.2.3-pyhf63ae98_0 --> 1.2.6-pyhf63ae98_0
  keyring                                     19.2.0-py37_0 --> 21.1.0-py37_0
  krb5                                    1.16.1-hc04afaa_7 --> 1.17.1-hc04afaa_0
  libcurl                                 7.67.0-h2a8f88b_0 --> 7.68.0-h2a8f88b_0
  libtiff                                  4.0.9-hb8ad9f9_1 --> 4.1.0-h56a325e_0
  libxml2                                  2.9.8-hadb2253_1 --> 2.9.9-h464c3ec_0
  libxslt                                 1.1.32-hf6f1972_0 --> 1.1.33-h579f668_0
  llvmlite                            0.30.0-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.31.0-py37ha925a31_0
  lxml                                 4.3.0-py37h1350720_0 --> 4.5.0-py37h1350720_0
  mkl                                            2018.0.2-1 --> 2020.0-166
  mkl-service                          1.1.2-py37hb217b18_4 --> 2.3.0-py37hb782905_0
  more-itertools     pkgs/main/win-64::more-itertools-7.2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::more-itertools-8.2.0-py_0
  numpydoc                                       0.9.1-py_0 --> 0.9.2-py_0
  openpyxl                                       3.0.2-py_0 --> 3.0.3-py_0
  openssl                                 1.1.1d-he774522_3 --> 1.1.1d-he774522_4
  packaging                                       19.2-py_0 --> 20.1-py_0
  pandoc                                1.19.2.1-hb2460c7_1 --> 2.2.3.2-0
  parso                                          0.5.1-py_0 --> 0.6.1-py_0
  path.py                                       12.0.2-py_0 --> 12.4.0-0
  pillow                               5.4.1-py37hdc69c19_0 --> 7.0.0-py37hcc1f983_0
  pip                                         19.3.1-py37_0 --> 20.0.2-py37_1
  py                                             1.8.0-py_0 --> 1.8.1-py_0
  pycurl                            7.43.0.3-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 7.43.0.5-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  pyodbc                              4.0.27-py37ha925a31_0 --> 4.0.30-py37ha925a31_0
  pyparsing                                      2.4.5-py_0 --> 2.4.6-py_0
  pyrsistent                          0.15.6-py37he774522_0 --> 0.15.7-py37he774522_0
  setuptools                                  42.0.2-py37_0 --> 45.2.0-py37_0
  six                                         1.13.0-py37_0 --> 1.14.0-py37_0
  sphinx                                         2.2.2-py_0 --> 2.4.0-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~                             1.1.2-py_0 --> 1.2.0-py_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  anaconda                                     5.2.0-py36_3 --> custom-py37_1
  console_shortcut                         0.1.1-h6bb2dd7_3 --> 0.1.1-3
  ipython                              7.9.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 5.8.0-py37_0
  pycosat                              0.6.3-py37hfa6e2cd_0 --> 0.6.3-py37he774522_0*


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

    Downloading and Extracting Packages zlib-1.2.11    | 110 KB    |            |   0%
```

And then I get the following error message:

> Could not find the entry point for the OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve procedure in the dynamic link library
>   c: \ PYTHON \ Anaconda \ Library \ bin \ libssl-1_1-x64.dll.

I've checked for corrupted windows files (there aren't), restarted the computer, tried to update libssl-1_1-x64.dll and the same error persists.

Comment: @KenWhite , I'm sorry, I didn't know! I corrected right now. Could you try to help me in this? I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked perfectly. 
There is two others files  **libssl-1_1-x64.dll** and **libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll**  in the path c:\Anaconda\DLLs with a different date.

Just copy them and paste in the path c:\Anaconda\Library\bin

Then you can go to Anaconda Prompt and run your update line code.

source: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003

I hope this tip could help others. I spent five hours trying to solve hahaha.
See you!